# How to delete a domain user with associated folder rights?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, samba, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019, windows-server-2022

Right now when I delete a user from the domain I get left with these folder rights remnants that I have to remove manually. I've noticed this on both Windows and Linux driven data servers. Is there a way to force client in a domain to automatically purge the folder rights for users that are no longer a part of the domain?

[Folder rights remnant example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m1di.png)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing builtin to clean up orphaned entries in the ACLs.

I suspect if [you search](https://www.google.com/search?q=clean+orphaned+acl+records) you will find several third party scripts or tools that could do some cleanup. I don't have any direct experience or strong opinions about them.

In general you should **avoid use users in ACLs**.  Instead you should be creating groups, and adding the users to group., then **using the groups in the ACLs**. If you do this you can simply remove a user from a group, and no filesystem changes need to be made, and no orphaned ACL eateries will be left.

Comment: I am already using groups, but I guess you're saying that I need to start using more specific groups, for example instead of a "USER" I would create a group for the job title, for example "ACCOUNTING" then allocate the user to that group and give the folder access to the group accounting?

Comment: Yes, role based groups.

Answer (score 0):

`Is there a way to force client in a domain to automatically purge the folder rights for users that are no longer a part of the domain?`

No, there is not. Generally, a "client" is not a good selection to perform general file system permissions management. Clients will not know about security principals they don't have access to, principals that do in fact exist, but for many reasons they are unable to resolve. Clients also may not perform activities that are expected, or create logs of the activities for the many issues that may result.

There are solutions on the market for file systems cleanup for principals that no longer exist. It's also fairly easy to create something like this.